# Teams tab authentication

Tags: authentication, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()` function but I'm really confused. When I call the function, a new tab is opened in my browser (Chrome) window and not within Teams itself. Is this normal behavior? The authentication works and redirects to a callback url where I call the `microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess()` function but it doesn't get back to the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()` success callback (always hits the failure callback). Is this an issue with `validDomains`? I'm pretty lost. Any help would be great! Thank you.

```
microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: "/auth",
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    successCallback: () => {
        alert("auth success")
        // Redirect to app
        window.location.href = "/app"
    },
    failureCallback: () => {
        alert("auth failure")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

I made the mistake of calling the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()` function on page load instead of on some user interaction like a login button click.

Reference: ["Add UI to your configuration or content page to enable the user to sign in when necessary. You should not drive the authentication pop-up without user action, because this is likely to trigger the browser's pop-up blocker."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication)

Comment: I have tried the same flow but the popup window does not close even if I call microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess("") or microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure(""). As suggested I am doing it on a login link click.  But if I click to close the popup, failure callback gets called.

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh did you ever solve the issue? Experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Hi @AlexP, Since this is more than 1 year old, I may not be able to resolve your exact issue but my issue was resolved after going through the [silent authentication doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-silent-aad)